# Property-based authorization of the IdentityUser class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I extended the `IdentityUser` class and added a property that references a school table, looking like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Guid? SchoolId { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in all the controllers in my application, I need to check if the logged in user has any schools linked to his registration. If not, access should be denied. I already have an `[Authorize(Roles = "admin, coordinator, librarian")]` to validate access, but this validation is based on roles. Now, I need that in addition to the roles, it is possible to check the `SchoolId` property.

How do I do this check? I didn't want to do the manual verification on each `Action`.

Comment: evaluate a claim based auth, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#apply-policies-to-mvc-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `HasSchoolPolicy` which is based upon a claim of `HasSchool`:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SchoolPolicy", policy =>
                      policy.RequireClaim("HasSchool"));
});
```

And at the IDP level each user should update its claim based on the `SchoolId` property with:

```
if (user.SchoolId.HasValue)
    await userMgr.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("HasSchool"))
```

And then you just add the notation over the controller method with:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SchoolPolicy", Roles = "...")]
```